# Date display format difference in STRSQL

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I've been wondering how fields with DECIMAL data type gets displayed in a date format when queried in STRSQL.

For instance, there are two fields, create date and change date in a table defined as decimal (7). But when you query this field through STRSQL, it gets displayed as

```
....+....1....+....2 
    Change     Create 
    Date       Date   
 117/06/16   95/05/27
```

How is this possible? I mean where does the Slashes come from?  I think this was defined as a PF pretty long back and the DDS is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able do duplicate your scenario using the EDTWRD keyword in this test DDS 
(DATE2 was a legit 'L' type date field for reference only).

```
    A          R TESTR                                         
    A            DATE1          7S 0       EDTWRD('   /  /  ')
    A            DATE2           L         DATFMT(*YMD)        
    A            DATE3          7S 0       EDTWRD('   /  /  ')
```

Then used DFU to enter your values in DATE1 and DATE3, 
which yielded this in a query:

```
    Line    ....+....1....+....2....+....3       
                DATE1  DATE2         DATE3       
    000001  117/06/16  17-07-18   95/05/27
```